# Issues while extracting with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm experimenting with Scrapy and currently trying the following

```
scrapy shell https://github.com/search?p=1&q=React+Django&type=Users

# FName LName
response.css(".mr-1::text").get()

# Headline
response.css(".mb-1::text").get()

# Location
response.css("#user_search_results .mr-3:nth-child(1)::text").get()

# Email
response.css(".Link--muted::attr(href)").get()
```

I'm now running into these two issues:

`response.css(".mb-1::text").get()`

> Expected: Software Engineer interested in Java, Python, Ruby, Groovy, Bash, Clojure, React-Native, and Docker. Focus: Testing, CI, and Micro-Services.

> Result: Software Engineer interested in Java, Python, Ruby, Groovy, Bash, Clojure,

`response.css(".Link--muted::attr(href)").get()`

> Expected: djangofan@gmail.com

> Result: None

Do you have any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `response.xpath('string(//p[@class="mb-1"])')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these cases use xpath instead of css, as there are multiple `.mb-1` and you need to isolate the first one and get the text including all of its child element.

Example:

```py
''.join(response.xpath('(//p[contains(@class, "mb-1")])[1]//text()').extract())
```

will give you:

```
Software Engineer interested in Java, Python, Ruby, Groovy, Bash, Clojure, React-Native, and Docker.  Focus: Testing, CI, and Micro-Services.
```

Comment: Aha, I see, thank you @Jahid. Do you have any advice on how to deal with the email which I tried with `response.css(".Link--muted::attr(href)").get()`. Still didn't figure that out.

Comment: I think the response body does not contains emails as these are dynamically generated. Moreover, I cannot see any API call through network tab that return emails. So, the only option is now to render the page. Try to use Scrapy-Splash